# Manually joining a trace created by a controller to a different trace in Sleuth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-cloud-sleuth

My system consists of a 3rd party server, to which I send a POST request, and the server sends back a POST request when it finishes calculating the result.
My project consists of Spring Cloud Stream applications, and I want this whole operation to be contained in a single Processor that maintains the same trace when sending the request and upon receiving the response via HTTP POST.

For this, I created a Processor application, with 2 classes:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class Client{
...
   @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
      public void sendToServer(Message<String> message){
      //also sends the traceId
      restTemplate.postForEntity(http://server-url,message.getPayload(),String.class);
   }
}
```

Second class:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@RestController
public class ResponseHandler{
    @RequestMapping("/{traceId}"), method=Request.POST)
    public void forwardResult(@RequestBody String body, @PathVariable("traceId") String traceId){
        long traceId = Long.parseLong(traceId);
        Message<String< message=  MessageBuilder.withPayload(body).setHeader("spanTraceId",traceId).build();
        processor.output().send(message);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because the new trace is created the moment the controller receives a request. I want the trace in the controller to be the same as before the request was sent.

Is there a better/working approach?

Comment: If you use the rest template as a bean then Sleuth will instrument the outgoing HTTP request with proper headers. On the recipient side you will continue the trace automatically. That should work out of the box.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak the recipient doesn't use Spring. I can pass via headers/url the trace id back to my controller, but I don't know how to translate that into the trace being created when the controller receives a request.

Comment: The recipient doesn't have to use Spring. It's enough that they use a ZIpkin compatible tracer.